# Toy Story 3 in Spanish

Tags: toy-story-3

What do they do on the Spanish version of Toy Story 3 when Buzz is set to Spanish mode?

Anyone out there who has seen the Spanish version?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [Toy Story 3 FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435761/faq#.2.1.22) in IMDB:

> In the Spanish versions of the film, during Buzz Lightyear's "Spanish
>   mode", he continues to speak Spanish rather than a different language
>   such as English. However, different accents and dialects are used
>   depending on the region. In the Latin American version, "normal" Buzz
>   uses the local Latin American variety of Spanish in the dubbed
>   version, but when he converts to "Spanish mode", he shifts to the
>   "standard" Castilian accent (from central Spain), which to native
>   speakers, sounds very different from Latin American Spanish. In Spain,
>   "normal" Buzz uses standard Castilian Spanish in the dubbed version,
>   and when he converts to Spanish mode, he then uses an exaggerated
>   Andalusian accent from southern Spain, which is appropriately the land
>   of flamenco and many other traditions identified as stereotypically
>   Spanish. Woody even responds to him with a mock imitation of this
>   Andalusian accent. In that way, the basic premise of the joke is
>   retained or even enhanced in the Spanish dubbed versions.

Comment: That's really cool. Other movies don't address that kind of situation at all. For instance, in the French version of the Home Alone movie where the family goes to Paris, everyone speaks French all the time, but then when a Frenchman walks up to the father, he tells him that he can't understand French.

Comment: @Phong: My personal favorite is from the Spanish translation of the first *Men In Black* movie. At the scene at the beginning with the illegal immigrants from Mexico, when K outs one of them that doesn't actually speak Spanish, the Spanish version handles it differently.  Because this is the Spanish translation and we're playing by a translation convention that everyone's  speaking Spanish normally, K calls the alien ugly, then when he doesn't respond appropriately, declares that he must be deaf as well!